# Why was Adnarim liberated?

Tags: lateral-thinking

There was just a brutal murder in a neighborhood. Police arrived on the scene as quickly as they could. Helicopters patrolled the area. One mile north of the crime, there was a running man by the name of Adnarim. He was the only one, within a few mile radius from the scene, outdoors, and therefore easily spotted by the nearby helicopter.

Police quickly confronted him, surrounded him, and interviewed him. The interview got more and more violent, but thankfully, there was a curious neighbor who left his house with his camera to check out what was going on.

Here's the recording:

```
Police 1: Hello, sir
Police 2: There has recently been a murder in the neighborhood of Sthgir. Where were you approximately 20 minutes ago?
Adnarim: *stutters* uh uhh I umm I'm not...
Police 1: We are not trying to harm you, just please tell us where you were.
*Adnarim tries to run away, police catch him*
Police 3: Sir! We demand that you answer the question!
Adnarim: No! Stop!
*Adnarim is put in a headlock by a policeman*
Police 2: Where were you!?
```

A couple minutes go by like this, until...

```
Adnarim: Fine! I'll admit it! I did it! I murdered that man. I've always hated the guy, Randaim, always stealing my thunder in our workplace. He got promoted instead of me! It was about time I got my revenge!
```

Adnarim is put into a police car and driven away.

He has a trial a month later, in which the witness put up the video as evidence. The case was clear; Adnarim was guilty.

But, he was not done with them. He ordered for his case to be brought up to the Court of Appeals. And it was, where he was unpredictably found guilty.

As stubborn as he is, he asks for it to be brought up to the Supreme Court.

The Supreme Court agreed that it was an interesting case, and decided to take it. As he was tried in the Supreme Court, things didn't look too good for him, for the prosecutor made a point that the video showed clear evidence of him stating that he did commit the crime and even the reason why he'd think of doing it. He was the only one within miles outside of their house. He then proclaimed that in the neighborhood of Sthgir, Adnarim was the only one that could have killed the victim.

The case is about to be closed, and Adnarim sentenced to 15 years in prison, until one thing.

Adnarim's lawyer remembered something, something that would change the entire court. He asked for permission to speak, and then said the sentence he was thinking of. The court is in awe. Adnarim is liberated, with no charge. He was declared innocent.

What was the sentence that Adniram's lawyer said that turned the tides for the Supreme Court?

**Bonus**: Why is Adnarim's name **Adnarim**? Why did he murder in the neighborhood of **Sthgir**?

Hints:

> There was no other evidence that Adnarim committed the crime besides the video and his confession about the crime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adnarim was not

> read his Miranda Rights, which are (popularly depicted as being) necessary for any interaction with the suspect to be admissible evidence in court. (Note that this is not *actually* how the law works, but it's how the law is depicted in media.)

The names are

> simply the words "Miranda" and "Rights" backwards.

Comment: Therefore a [tag:knowlegde] tag is required.

Comment: Man, I thought this would take longer. Nice job!

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi: Backwards words are *very* easy to spot. "Adniram" was almost normal (though I still noticed it nearly immediately), but even if I hadn't, "sghtir" was obvious enough to give the whole thing away.

Comment: @Deusovi Do I need to point out that "sghtir" is NOT "rights" backwards?

Comment: @BmyGuest I wrote "Sthgir", not "Sghtir"

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi Yes, he's referring to the typo in my comment.

Comment: +1, @Deusovi for pointing out very unambiguously that this is completely not how the law works. The media has done enough to misinform the public on this...

Comment: Just a question - is 'Adnarim was not read his...' intentional? It seems like a strange way to start a sentence.